# Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialMetadata.PARTIAL_UPDATE

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

I am trying to disable comments on linkedin posts .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/social-metadata-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=curl#enable-or-disable-comments-on-a-thread

Error message I get is :
Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialMetadata.PARTIAL_UPDATE.20231101
status:403,serviceErrorCode:100,code:ACCESS_DENIED

Does anyone have idea regarding this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more clues about how to [post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

looks like your version of API "20231101" is deprecated

EDIT:
also you should check required permissions
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/xxx/products/community-management-api/endpoints?version=yyy

looks like scopes required for endpoint:*/rest/socialMetadata/{entity}* , for method:*PARTIAL_UPDATE* are *w_member_social_feed* and/or *w_organization_social_feed*

note that according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/social-metadata-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http#access-to-social-actions-apis
scopes changed migrated from **w_member_social** to **w_member_social_feed** and **w_organization_social** to **w_organization_social_feed**

Comment: also check if you have access to Community Management API in your app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/community-management-api-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2023-11

Comment: Can you suggest how to deactive comments of linkedIN posts using API calls?

Comment: Also when I chaneg scopes from w_member_social to w_member_social_feed and w_organization_social to w_organization_social_feed , it's stops working for content sharing

Comment: I don't have access to Community Management API also I can't request it . It shows that :This API product requires that it be the only product on the application for legal and security reasons.
This product cannot be requested because there are currently other provisioned products or other pending product requests. A new developer application can be created to request this product.

Comment: as for the community management API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/community-management-api-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2023-11#frequently-asked-questions-faq
FAQ, 1 st question. apparently you need to create a new app, request communitymanagementAPI, finish the review, then apply for "merging" accesses of the  apps.